# ASP.NET use data retrieved from SQL in API weblink/Weblink

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml

im trying to use data im storing in my SQL DB and put it into a API Weblink;

the link im trying to get data from  is:

```
https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID=[SQLDATA]&&vCODE=[OTHERSQLDATA]
```

so just to be clear at the end of this i want it to look like this:

```
    https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID=[123]&&vCODE=[1234]
```

I'm having trouble as i don't know how to get the data from my SQL and enter it into a this weblink.

here is some code;

```
            SqlConnection conn = null;

        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT ApiKey, VeriF FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @username";

            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["READER"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            SqlParameter UserN = new SqlParameter();
            UserN.ParameterName = "@username";
            UserN.Value = User.Identity.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(UserN);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query not a non-query, so replace the execute with:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then get the data with:

```
string url;

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    url = string.Format(
        "https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID=[{0}]&&vCODE=[{1}]",
        reader.GetString(0),
        reader.GetString(1));
}
else
{
    url = null; // username not found
}
```

Now you have the `url` or `null`, if the initial `username` was wrong.
If you print out the `url` you should get a valid URL as expected.

Comment: after i've called this i then get a web XML that i need to break down.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. You get an XML from the database?

Comment: no, let me give you the full link:https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH

Comment: so the 2 bits of data im getting from my SQL DB  is 4602486 and BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH

Comment: The first is the `keyID` you were longing for. The second is the `vCODE` I presume. That's what you were asking for. Build the string as I've shown you and that's the URL you needed. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    return string.Format(
                        "https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID={0}&&vCODE={1}",
                        reader.GetString(0),
                        reader.GetString(1));
                }

Comment: I've tried manually the URL and get this error message: `Must provide userID or keyID parameter for authentication.` So that's the answer to your question. The error you get is something entirely different and requires a separate approach.

Comment: I've modified the answer to be a little bit easier to understand. That is the answer you needed. If the `url` is not valid you must debug it and try to find the error. I cannot help you in that.